# Quebrar a linha após uma determinada palavra com PHP

Tags: php

Colegas,

Estou fazendo uma busca interna em um site existente, porém em um dos resultados, está trazendo da seguinte forma:

```
 <a href=".....">página 1</a>&nbsp;<a href=".....">página 2</a>&nbsp;<a
 href=".....">página 3</a>
```

Como eu faria para que após a palavra **< /a>** houvesse uma quebra de linha com PHP?

Comment: Nos mostre o que você já tentou e quais erros está enfrentando. Uma dica é a utilização da função explode();

Comment: `após a palavra ""` deveria ter uma palavra entre as aspas?  Ou quer dar um quebra de linha em um ponto vazio mesmo? Existem diversas maneiras, depende um pouco de como vem o resultado etc...

Comment: Não reparei... ajustei agora. Seria depois da palavra </ a>

Comment: Já tentei o explode(). porém ele me retorna sempre a primeira linha. Vale lembrar que nem todos os resultados trazem dessa forma...

Comment: quebrar em todos os `</a>` ou somente em alguns especificos

Comment: Quebrar em todos, pois nesse resultado específico , está trazendo um ao lado do outro.

Comment: usa `str_replace("</a>", "</a><br>", $tua_variavel);`

Comment: Funcionou Thiago. Obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acredito que isso resolve pra você

```
$text = '<a href=".....">página 1</a>&nbsp;<a href=".....">página 2</a>&nbsp;<a href=".....">página 3</a>';
$newtext = str_replace('</a>', '</a><br />', $text);
```

Ou se preferir pode quebrar nos `&nbsp;`

```
$newtext = str_replace('&nbsp;', '<br />', $text);
```

problema é que pode afetar outras areas que tenham isso e voce nao queira uma quebra de linha

Comment: Perfeito... Funcionou! Obrigado!